# can anyone help me how to get value from the given example , as im new to swift

Tags: swift

From this json i want to retrieve the values of the key "name" and "image"

```
  ["count": 12, "results": [{
        "pk": 6,
        "fields": {
            "name": "Kids Wear",
            "image": "[imag.jpg]",

        }
```

I have got error as `**[ "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"]` when i tried to get  value using below code

```
let val = (json["results"]!)

val[0]["fields"] as [string:Any]
```

Comment: There are 160 search results for `[swift] Type 'Any' has no subscript members` on SO. I am confident that some of them will help to solve your problem.

Comment: im new to swift can you help me to get the value of fields "name"

Comment: Can you paste again the JSON properly?

Comment: ["count": 6, "results": [{
  
  "pk": 6,
  "fields": {
   "name": "Ethnic Wear",
   "image": "[imag.jpg]"
   
  }
 }]

Comment: try this val[0]["fields"] as [String:String]

Comment: got same error as Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: You have to cast `json["results"]` to `[[String:Any]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Swift Codable class to get relevant data

```
private func getResponse() {
let json = "{count: 6,results: [{pk: 6,fields: {name: Ethnic Wear,image:[imag.jpg]}}]}"

let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
    guard let results = response.results else {
        return
    }

    let pk = results[0].pk ?? 0
    let fields = results[0].fields

} catch _ {

}
}

print(getResponse())

// Response.swift

import Foundation
struct Response : Codable {
       let count : Int?
       let results : [Results]?

}
```

Comment: if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String: Any]
                {
                   let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
                    
                } got Error has Value of type[String:Any] has no member data

Comment: But I am able to get the response? did you try it with Codable?

Comment: The CodingKeys and the `init(from` method are not necessary. If the struct members are optional the decoder calls `decodeIfPresent` implicitly.

Comment: Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'data' is my error when using the code let data = json.data(using: .utf8)

Comment: @vadian sir, I know that already.

Comment: @iosDev `json` variable contains your JSON string response only and it's a `String` type variable.